# ActiveMQ Artemis logfile name

Tags: activemq-artemis, jboss-logging

I'm trying to modify the name of the logfile that is created by Artemis to include the hostname.

In the logging.properties under the broker instance, I've the below defined.

```
# File handler configuration
handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler
handler.FILE.level=DEBUG
handler.FILE.properties=suffix,append,autoFlush,fileName
handler.FILE.suffix=.yyyy-MM-dd
handler.FILE.append=true
handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
handler.FILE.fileName=${artemis.instance}/log/artemis_${hostname}.log
handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN
```

Somehow the `${artemis.instance}` gets resolved correctly, however the `${hostname}` is not being evaluated.

I'm not sure where `artemis.instance` is defined, so I can define `hostname` the same way? Or if there is a way to access the hostname some other way? I'm running on Redhat environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system property `artemis.instance` is defined in the `bin/artemis` script. However, you can just use `bin/artemis.profile` and set `-Dhostname=myHost` there in `JAVA_ARGS`.